# CRM 2011: Nothing happens when click on Export Translations

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I Want to translate my custom entities in CRM 2011. Therefor i go to customize the system on the settings page and then i click "Export Translations". The only thing that happens is a dialog box is shown with message:

> ---
>
> Exporting customized labels for translation can take several minutes. Do not click the export link again until the first export has finished. Are you sure that you want to export now?

When i click OK, nothing happens anymore. What should i do to get my translations?

EDIT: When i try to export the translations for a sollution with only a few entities in it, everything works. It seems only a few custom entities are "affected".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long do you wait? Have you looked into the EventLog or Trace on the server?

Comment: It was running during the night. Nothing happens. Never. I'm making a tempory sollution now with only a few entities in it. Exporting translations for this sollution works. In which folder can i find the EventLog?

Answer (score 1):

Thomas,

To find the "EventLog", you should look in the "EventViewer" of the "CRM"-server! There you can find all logs that happens concerning the "CRM" actions.